# TensorFlow Boolean Tensor Operations Equivalents

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I am looking for TensorFlow equivalents to the following Numpy operations

[Comparison](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/reference/routines.logic.html)

- `allclose(a, b[, rtol, atol, equal_nan])`    Returns `True` if two arrays
  are element-wise equal within a tolerance.
- `isclose(a, b[, rtol, atol, equal_nan])` Returns a boolean array where two arrays are element-wise equal within a tolerance.
- `all(a[, axis, out, keepdims])`  Test whether all array elements along a given axis evaluate to `True`.
- `any(a[, axis, out, keepdims])`  Test whether any array element along a
  given axis evaluates to `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no ops that do exactly the same thing for `allclose` or `isclose`, but you can have workarounds.

`isclose`: combine `tf.abs`, `tf.sub`, `tf.less` or `tf.less_equal`.

`allclose`: based on isclose, use `tf.reduce_all` in addition

`all`: use `tf.reduce_all`

`any`: use `tf.reduce_any`

Comment: Can you explain how to do `isclose` in more detail, the exact implementation?